# Checking for internet connection

Tags: ruby

How to check for internet connection using Ruby.

Comment: Why do you need to?  You should add more detail, because this will get downvoted as it is

Comment: Also let us know which platform you're on. Detecting a connection to the internet depends on the platform. Even then you wouldn't be able to distinguish an internet connection from a network connection without sending any packets

Comment: Sorry for not being detailed. I am trying to code an app to fetch an XML file from a website. Intended platform will be Win32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) and 'pinging' a reliable URL such as Google and check for an exception indicating they do not have an internet connection.

Comment: Trying example.com would seems more reliable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Ping` is deprecated in Ruby 1.9.x as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317838

A more future-proof, as well as more code-relevant solution would be the solution given by that answer, using `open-uri` and returning false on exception.